# Convert DEC value into hexadecimal in a table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Actually I guess the question is duplicate, but I didn't understand whats the WRONG with my SQL code. My error is

> Notice: Undefined index: CI in
>   C:\wamp\www\LOCATIONVIEWER\exampleDB.php on line 30.

I need to convert all  decimal value of column into hexadecimal value. Help me to do it... :)

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "locationviewer";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//CI is a column name of the table
$sql = "SELECT CONV(CI,10,16) FROM locationdata";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "CI: " . $row["CI"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();


?>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONV(CI,10,16) FROM locationdata";
```

To

```
$sql = "SELECT CONV(CI,10,16) AS `CI` FROM locationdata";
```

this issue happened because php can not see CI index and current index is somthing like CONV(CI,10,16)